# Modeling kind-of-random discrete events in a set period of time

Tags: neural-networks, generalized-linear-model

I'm looking to consider models which provide a probability distribution of the [number of tweets from a given account](https://www.predictit.org/Market/2948/) by a certain point in a week (e.g. noon on Tuesday) given a the set of events part way through the week. From the "undergraduate statistics" level of complexity, a Poisson distribution seems like an appropriate start.

Given that a part of a week has passed, however, what are possible models which can take into account an unusually active week, extra weights like popularity of a tweet, the possibility of an event triggering a lull, or other more complex phenomena? NN's seems like they should be capable of this. How can discrete events and progress through a time period be encoded as NN inputs? Is there a general name for this problem?

Meta-note: looking for a set of starting points for this as a research project rather than concrete solutions.

Comment: How much data do you have? I would start with something simpler than nn, such as poisson regression (possibly corrected for overdispersion)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't seen your repost on Cross Validated or Data Science, so I'll offer an answer here.

Your problem seems like a good fit for Bayesian modeling. A priori, you start off with a distribution over $\lambda$, the parameter for your Poisson distribution, representing your beliefs in what number of tweets are likely.

As you receive information, you can use Bayes rule to update your beliefs in $\lambda$, allowing you to incorporate events or a particularly active week.

$$P(\lambda | events) = \frac{P(events | \lambda) P(\lambda)}{P(events)$$

Comment: @Andrey askes for neural network....

Comment: "Meta-note: looking for a set of starting points for this as a research project rather than concrete solutions.", and "I'm looking to consider models which provide a probability distribution..." I think it's reasonable to offer alternative models than NNs.

Comment: This is good, too. Although other answers involving NN's would be "more correct". Sorry I haven't gotten a chance to re-post. I've set aside some time to look into Cross Validated and Data Science and post there today.